# Application with private framework "could not inspect application package" in Xcode 6. Missing framework info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

My application built and ran just fine in Xcode 5. I upgraded to Xcode 6 yesterday and now the application builds, but will not run on my device or in simulator.

I'm getting the error "could not inspect application package" when trying to run.

I checked my device logs (XCode > Windows > Devices) and after trying to run the application, I get the following error in my log:

> Sep 23 10:32:46 XXXXXX's-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5476] :
>   __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:203: Failed to install application at
>   file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/ActivateMachines.app/ : Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x1355075a0
>   {Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load
>   Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.5lz5TS/extracted/ActivateMachines.app/Frameworks/GeLoSDK.framework}

I've checked that the GeLoSDK.framework does have a Resources/Info.plist file.

I'm using this framework: 
https://github.com/GeLoInc/GeLoSDK-iOS

It should be linked properly, as it was working on Xcode 5.

Did something change in Xcode 6 that I'm not aware of? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the application to build by moving the framework into "/Library/Frameworks" and adding it to the project from there.

Previously, I had been using the framework by bundling it in with the application directly and linking the binary manually. This worked fine in Xcode 5, but not in Xcode 6.

I'm not sure if this is a new bug in Xcode 6, or what changed, but using "/Library/Frameworks" solved the problem.

Comment: I wonder if being inside of Library/Frameworks triggers something allowing deep bundles which aren't allowed for bundles located elsewhere.  In any event, I'm glad you found a solution.  It's likely that your claim of it working in Xcode 5 but not Xcode 6 is probably a tad off.  I suspect the issue is more likely with installd changes in iOS 8 compared to iOS 7 than tools changes.

Comment: I can't believe this worked. Apple is absolutely ridiculous sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem with the GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework:

> com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[522]: Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to
>   load Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5E6B8A7-017D-4FC2-9C22-0698DFD0AC13/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Ha6x7D/extracted/XXX-ios.app/Frameworks/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework}
>   configd[54]: inet_set_autoaddr(en0, 1) failed, Resource busy (16)

What worked for me was removing GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework from the Embed Frameworks in Build Phases for my app target.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 3):

if you keep having problem in running app with custom framework and the log from simulator are as following:

> Oct 21 16:27:54 bunnydembp
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[1936]: Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7fb7954c16c0
>   {Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load
>   Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/bunny/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/10D9FDBC-13B5-420B-9B9E-365E05551830/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.4mi9Mn/extracted/radio365.app/Frameworks/SOME.framework}

you need to `add/alias info.plist` in framework sub path like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Dz2.png

if you use the build script from http://blog.db-in.com/universal-framework-for-ios/ 
you can just add following in line 44

```
#ios8 bug in xcode 6.0.1 and 6.1
ln -s "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/Info.plist" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Info.plist"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you really don't have an Info.plist in that bundle but that the error was being ignored and not reported in previous versions.  Make sure you are really installing your Info.plist for GeLoSDK.framework.

Comment: Where exactly should I be checking? I've looked inside the 'ActivateMachines.app/Frameworks/GeLoSDK.framework' directory, and there is a 'Resources' folder that contains an 'Info.plist' file

Comment: I suspect that's the problem.  iOS uses shallow bundles whereas OS X uses deep bundles.  It looks like your GeLoSDK.framework is building as if for OS X (deep) rather than for iOS (shallow).  From your link, it looks like you're just using the built framework provided by a 3rd party.  You can possibly fix it yourself by moving all the files up and flattening it yourself (you will also likely need to run install_name_tool to change the identifier of the binary), but I suggest you just poke the maintainer of that framework to build you a fixed version.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Jeremy. How should I flatten it? As in what file structure should the framework resemble after making it "shallow"? Do you have a link to any references for that? http://www.meonbinary.com/2013/07/creating-universal-ios-framework
says that the file structure the framework uses should be okay.

Comment: Take a look at UIKit.framework (or others) in the iPhoneSimulator SDK for example /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks ... note their file structure has everything inside of the .framework directly rather than a Versions/A/Contents/Resources subdirectory.  Try mimicing that and see if it fixes the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I actually figured out another solution finally, but you helped me to start thinking in the right direction.

Comment: @AnthonyM what was the solution you finally figured out?

Comment: @YoCoh I provided my answer and marked it as correct. It's below.

Comment: thanks @AnthonyM. I realized my problem was stemming from the way  Xcode 6's target "BUILD ALL" contains a run script within its iOS Framework target that is incorrectly creating the .framework file's  folder structure - hence causing the error you reported (as well as a simulator error). I used a different run script (from http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) and that fixed my problem.